# link two dropdown lists in formview in c#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a web page with two dropdowns in formview. I want to change items in the second dropdown when the user selects an item in the first dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the first dropdown and then, in that event's code, bind the second one. Also, you have to set `AutoPostBack="True"` on your first dropdown.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged.aspx

You might also want to put the two dropdowns inside an `UpdatePanel`, to avoid posting the entire page each time.